# How to avoid Singleton when Spring managed bean and Pojo depend on same service

Tags: java, json, spring, oop, singleton

I am looking for the alternative design to singleton pattern given the following preconditions:

- There is/are Spring managed bean(s) which use some utility service
- There is/are POJOs which use the same utility service
- Implementation of service should be easy to mock/swap

There is `JacksonMapper` which implements `JsonStringConverter` interface.

The POJO is some custom object created by Builder pattern, like example bellow, that is using implementation of interface JsonStringConverter.

```
public class User {

    private static final JsonStringConverter jsonStringConverter = JacksonMapper.getInstance();

    private String name;
    //...

    private User (User builder) {

       this.name = builder.name;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public String toJson() {

        Map<String, String> jsonMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        jsonMap.put(UserAtributes.NAME.getDescription(), this.name);

        return jsonStringConverter.toJson(jsonMap);
    }

    public static class UserBuilder {

        private String name;
        //...


    public UserBuilder name(String name) {

        this.name = name;

        return this;
    }

    public User build() {

        return new User(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Since instances of `User` are not managed by the Spring, i cannot inject  implementation of `JsonStringConverter` into User with `@Autowire` annotation.

On the other hand, there are Spring managed Beans which use same implementation of that interface to convert some other maps to Json String. But since i already have an instance of converter cached outside Spring IOC, rather then creating new object inside IOC just for injection, i also poll it with getInstance() in bean. This is the part i don't like at all.

This is the Singleton in question:

```
public class JacksonMapper implements JsonStringConverter {

    private static final ObjectMapper jsonToMap;
    private static final ObjectMapper mapToJson;

    private static final JacksonMapper INSTANCE;

    static 
    {
        INSTANCE = new JacksonMapper();
        jsonToMap = new ObjectMapper();
        mapToJson = new ObjectMapper();
    }

   /**
    * Exists to defeat instantiation
    */
    private JacksonMapper() {
    // not called
    }

    public static JacksonMapper getInstance() {

        return INSTANCE;
    }

 // methods...
}
```

Options i see right now:

- Let JsonStringConverter be class with static methods for conversion from and to Json. Spring managed beans and POJOs can now use that Utility class instead of Singleton.

**Cons:** i would prefer to use explicit interface between `JsonStringConverter` and client code, for mocking and possibility to swap implementation easily.

- Use Singleton pattern

**Cons:** requirement to have unnecessary object in memory to call method that should have been static to begin with.

Could somebody point me to a third reasonable option for the above situation ?

Please note that this is general question, not tied to this specific use case, when there is dependency on same service for both Spring managed beans and POJOs.

Comment: You say that you have an instanced "cached outside Spring"--when is it initialized, and how do your classes obtain it? Are you talking about that private static field?

Comment: Added Singleton example for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just register your singleton as a Spring bean:

```
@Configuration
public class SingletonWrapperConfig {
    @Bean
    public JacksonMapper jacksonMapper() {
        return JacksonMapper.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Note that in a case like this, it's recommended to make `JacksonMapper` an `enum` instead of an ordinary class as part of the "enum singleton" pattern.

Comment: This definitely resolves my issue with DI of custom Singleton to Spring Beans without creating redundant objects. Is there perhaps technique to inject Bean into Pojo ? I had some mixed success with:  SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this). Sometimes this lets me autowire into pojo and sometimes it does not, yet i don't see what makes the difference.